# Example of open $O\subset \mathbb R$ dense s.t. $O\neq \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Baire's theorem says that intersection of open sets that are dense is still dense. For me, the first dense set I'm thinking to in $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ but no of those sets are open (and Baire's theorem doesn't apply for those set). Could someone give me an example of open set $\mathcal O\subset \mathbb R$ that is dense in $\mathbb R$ and such that $\mathcal O\neq \mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting example is the following: Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, we can enumerate them as a sequence $r_n$.

Let 
$$
O:= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (r_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, r_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})
$$

Then $O$ is open, contains all rational numbers and hence is dense, but has a total measure of $1$, thus it is "much smaller" than $\mathbb R$.

Comment: beautiful example :-)

Answer (score 4):

$\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, for instance. For the record, Baire's theorem says that the intersection of a **countable** family of dense open subsets (of a complete metric space) is dense.

Answer (score 4):

$$\mathbf R\smallsetminus\mathbf Z=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbf Z}(n, n+1) $$
is another example.

Answer (score 2):

For example  $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty).$